# O que é e para que serve o < br clear="all" >?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, ui

Lembro que antigamente era comum ver esse `<br clear="all">` em códigos fonte. Mas sempre me perguntei para que esse *clear all*?

Qual é a diferença de um `<br>` para um `<br clear="all">`? Quando devo usar um ou outro?

Comment: Mas pq você usaria `clear="all"` se está **deprecated** no Html5?

Comment: @LeAndrade deve ser por isso que não vejo mais por ai rss. Se vc puder poste uma resposta sobre isso e com a fonte ;)

Comment: Pior que está tão deprecated Hugo, que não consigo imaginar nada para realizar um exemplo :)

Comment: @LeAndrade rapaz no teste que fiz aqui coloquei um br clear all entre duas divs com float, ai a segunda div caiu pra linha de baixo, e tipo um clearfix pelo que me pareceu

Comment: Hugo parece ser isto mesmo pelo que li tbm, como disse não há mais muita informação sobre este atributo Html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A propriedade clear é uma propriedade utilizada para limpar qualquer alinhamento a direita ou a esquerda daquele elemento.

Se você utilizar essa propriedade você estará limpando de todos os lados ("all") floats de alinhamento.

É indicado hoje a utilização de

```
<br style="clear:left;"/>
```

Uma vez que o layout é todo configurado no CSS como boa prática.
** exemplo utilizado de css inline é indicado apenas como exemplo, não como boa prática também.

Answer (score 2):

O atributo `clear` é um atributo usado para limpar alinhamentos pré-existentes. Isso garante que o conteúdo após o `<br>` apareça abaixo da linha de base do elemento alinhado anteriormente.

No passado, essa abordagem geralmente era usada para interromper o conteúdo em torno de uma imagem ou tabela alinhada à direita ou à esquerda.

Este exemplo mostra um `<br>` com o qual um atributo `clear` é usado para levar o conteúdo abaixo de uma imagem alinhada à direita:

```
<p> <img src = "pool.jpg" alt = "sentado à beira da piscina" align = "right" />
   Texto 1
  <br clear="all"/>
    Texto 2
</p>
```

Fonte: https://www.sitepoint.com/clear-html-attribute/